# Cheap way to generate 1/4 circle curve

Tags: math, geometry

[image]
I have a value increasing linearly (blue line in diagram)
I'd like the output to look like a quarter of a circle (red line)
I *could* work this out using the [parametric equation of a circle](http://www.mathopenref.com/coordparamcircle.html) However this involves calculating the angle. I'm wondering if there is some way of doing this that involves less calculations (this code is going in a shader so I want it to be well optimised)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the [Bresenham's Midpoint Circle Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm), which has a nice integer-only implementation.. and C# code on the Wiki page, easy for porting.

Comment: thanks! I get it (and feel dumb now!) Its like drawing a succession of right angle triangles for which we know the lenght of the hypotenuse (radius) and one other side (x coordinate in my diagram)